# fixing image on the wordpress site using css class

Tags: wordpress

I want to fix a image on wordpress site by giving url in style.css but it not working..
I tried this code

//style.css

```
.image_link{
 background: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/images.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
 width:291;
 height:182;
}
```

I called it in edit post like,

```
<img class="image_link" alt="wp" />
```

But this is not working...

Comment: Please show us your code and explain some attempts. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am beginner of wordpress.. i know to post the content to my site.. But i dont know how to fix it in horizontally with corresponding contents.

Comment: post your code. what you have tried?

Comment: I dont know what to do? Can anyone tell about this?